# Bounded subset and Lebesgue's density theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have a bounded subset of the real numbers. Call this subset $A$.  Assume that $A$ has nonzero measure. Can I show that there is an interval from the real numbers such that almost every number in that interval has to be an element of $A$? Is Lebesgue's density theorem sufficient for this?

Comment: Take a subset of $A$?

Comment: I want an interval from the real numbers. I don't know whether $A$ has a subset that is an interval.

Comment: But then how do you want to show that there is an interval such that almost every point in that interval has to be an element of $A$? If $A$ doesn't have an interval then your question is no.

Comment: If the interval may have length zero the answer is yes.  If the interval must have positive length, the answer is not necessarily.

Comment: The reason I said not necessarily is that there are [Cantor-like sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) with positive Lebesgue measure.  They are closed with empty interior.  I think a set like that cannot achieve its Lebesgue density at any point in which the density is one on any interval of positive length containing that point.  I'm not sure though, or how to prove it.

Comment: Thank you! I think this makes it clear.